# how to add AWS API gateway with application load balancer for ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

How to integrate API gateway with application load balancer? I have integrated ECS with ALB, now I want to add API gateway in front without lambda. But I got confused how to connect API gateway with ALB..

Answer (score 3):

What you're probably looking for is the [HTTP Proxy Integration as described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/setup-http-integrations.html?shortFooter=true)

The basic idea is this:

1. Set up your API-Gateway with a greedy path like `/{proxy+}` on the `ANY` Method
2. Set the backend-endpoint to `https://my-alb-endpoint.com/ecs-service-bla/{proxy}`
3. (hopefully) success

**To make this work, your backend needs to be exposed to the internet (or at least reachable for the API Gateway)!**

You probably should keep your backend within a locked down VPC, but for this you're going to need to set up [a private integration, which requires a Network Load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html?shortFooter=true) - this might be costlier, but would be the recommended approach.

Comment: Hi @maurice, I am using API gateway with ALB. to make it secure as you said to use network load balancer with private endpoint. But after using network load balancer, how to forward api to respective microservices as I did in ALB? you have any idea about that? Also multipart data is not working in API gateway, it converts my file content to binary and not able to decode it in my API.

Comment: as answers go "hopefully success" is very poor.

Comment: These document discusses private integration:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/best-practices-api-gateway-private-apis-integration/best-practices-api-gateway-private-apis-integration.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/best-practices-api-gateway-private-apis-integration/http-api.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do . Inside API Gateway under integration type select HTTP and then provide complete path of ALB with endpoint resource.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30839146)